# Strange number of Careers invites added

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Is it ok that I've been rewarded three times in a day for the same number of invites?

It seems that there can be a bug: I don't think that I deserved that much number of invites:
[image]

Comment: maybe its a bonus for referrals ? or something like that ?

Comment: The initial bonus of 11 invitations is from the github integration, but it's strange that after this bonus in the same day came two bonuses with the same number of invites.

Comment: Looks like we had a bit of code doing redundant invites. Will have a fix in place soon. Invite some people!

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed at some point, just doing some housecleaning.